# Matching Field Names option not working during import to FileMaker with CSV

Tags: csv, filemaker

I have created product table with filed name product_id, prod_name and description. But while importing field from [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) file fields in [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) file are not matching.
Please any one tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

CSV files don't include field names so you can't use the Matching Names optio.

But you can drag the fields up and down so that they match up and then in a script you can import by last order.

Answer (score 0):

I found that checking the box marked "Don't import first record (contains field names)" tells FM that the first row contains field names and then the "matching names" option for arrange by becomes available. I'm in FM Pro 16 and using MS Excel (.xlsx) format to import.